# Parsing xml that contains new line characters within nodes

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the XML from a URL in Xcode. The trouble I am having is with new line characters within the nodes. When I parse the following XML, I am getting the address perfectly fine but not the name or description. Also, if there happens to be a "&" symbol, the parser stops parsing. How do I get around these two obstacles?

Here is an example XML I am trying to parse:

```
    <item>
        <Name>
            John Smith
        </Name>
        <Address>555 WHITEHEAD ST, Greenville, NY 55555</Address>
        <Description>
            Brick house - white trim
        </Description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Name>
            Jane Smith
        </Name>
        <Address>555 WHITEHEAD ST, Greenville, NY 55555</Address>
        <Description>
            Brick house - white trim & stone drive
        </Description>
    </item>
```

Here is the code I am using to parse the XML:

```
-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString {

arrests = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];

return self;
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName       namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    currentArrest = [[ArrestObject alloc] init];
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"]) {
    return;
}
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    [self.arrests addObject:currentArrest];

    currentArrest = nil;
}
else {
    [currentArrest setValue:currentNodeContent forKey:elementName];

    currentNodeContent = nil;
}
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foundCharacters:` can be called more than once per element. You need to append each string you get to your `currentNodeContent` variable, not just set it. So basically, reset `currentNodeContent` in the `didStartElement` method and use the fully appended value in the `didEndElement` method.

And you can't use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` to get rid of the newlines because that only removes the whitespace from the ends of the string, not the middle.

Lastly, the problem with the `&` character is simple - it's not a valid character in XML. Whenever you need an actual `&` character in your XML, you need to use `&amp;`, like in HTML. Same for `<` and `>` - use `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

Update:

In `didStartElement` do:

```
currentNodeContent = [NSMutableString string];
```

In `foundCharacters` do:

```
[currentModeContent appendString:string];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm fairly new to Xcode. How exactly should I go about appending each string to currentNodeContent, since it is a NSMutableString? And in the didStartElement, I should reset currentNodeContent by using currentNodeContent = nil?